# Writing to a file using write() is adding nuls all over the place, how to remove them?

Tags: c, file-writing, nul

I am having some issues using write(). I am writing a 2d array to a .txt file but when it gets written to the file a bunch of NUL chars(not NULL) get added to the file. so I went searching around and found this to remove [characters](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-all-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string/) but was of no help I tried removing \0, 00, not sure how to deal with the nuls.
trying some things out I tried doing `sizeof(table[0][0])` would give me 4 then I did `strncpy(buffer, table[0][0], 2)` but I guess it doesn't work like that and was of no help.

This is part of my program, I can post the rest if needed.

update:Added whole program at bottom

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    char *table[8][8] = {{NULL}};
    int fdi;
    char *buffer; 
    char msg[1] = "\n";
    char msg1[1] = ",";

    fdi = open("board.txt", O_RDWR);
    if (fdi != -1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                buffer = table[i][j];
                //strcpy(buffer,table[i][j]);
                write(fdi, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                write(fdi, msg1, sizeof(msg1));
            }
            write(fdi, msg, sizeof(msg));
        }
        close(fdi);
    }
}
```

This is the output I get[image: I get]

This is what I'm wanting to get[image: to get]

Thanks for any input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // For exit() function
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>//throwing a warning write() seems to work fine without it
#define MAXC 1024
int getColRow(char *input)
{
   int val = 0;
   for (int i = 0; input[i]; i++)
   {
       input[i] = tolower(input[i]);
   }
   switch (input[0])
   {
   //row
   case 97:
       val = 0;
       break;
   case 98:
       val = 1;
       break;
   case 99:
       val = 2;
       break;
   case 100:
       val = 3;
       break;
   case 101:
       val = 4;
       break;
   case 102:
       val = 5;
       break;
   case 103:
       val = 6;
       break;
   case 104:
       val = 7;
       break;
   //col
   case 49:
       val = 7;
       break;
   case 50:
       val = 6;
       break;
   case 51:
       val = 5;
       break;
   case 52:
       val = 4;
       break;
   case 53:
       val = 3;
       break;
   case 54:
       val = 2;
       break;
   case 55:
       val = 1;
       break;
   case 56:
       val = 0;
       break;
   default:
       break;
   }
   return val;
}

int main()
{
   char c[1000];
   char ch[1000];
   FILE *fp, *fd, *op;
   char word[1000], *token;
   char *table[8][8] = {{NULL}};
   int i = 0;
   int j = 0;
   char input[50];
   char *endPos;
   char *buffer;
   char *exit = "exit";
   char *show = "show";
   char *move = "mv";
   char *cp = "cp";
   char *prq = "prq";
   char *prr = "prq";
   char *prb = "prb";
   char *prk = "prk";
   int a0Row, b0Col, a1Row, b1Col;
   int fdi;

int len = 10;

if ((fp = fopen("board.txt", "r")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Error! opening file");
    return 0;
}

// if ((fd = fopen("board.txt", "r")) == NULL)
// {
//     printf("Error! opening file");
//     return 0;
// }

//print csv file(formated) one first time to see starting board
// while (fgets(ch, MAXC, fd))
// {
//     for (char *tok = strtok(ch, ","); tok; tok = strtok(NULL, ","))
//     {
//         size_t len;
//         tok[strcspn(tok, "\n")] = 0; /* trim '\n' from end tok */
//         printf("%s ", tok);
//     }
//     printf("\n");
// }

//fill array
while (fscanf(fp, "%3s", c) != EOF)
{
    token = strtok(c, ",");
    len = strlen(token);
    //printf("%s ", token);
    table[i][j] = malloc(len + 1);

    memcpy(table[i][j++], token, len + 1);
    if (j >= 8)
    {
        i++;
        j = 0;
        //printf("\n");
    }
}

do
{
    int counter1 = 8;
    int counter2 = 8;
    fd = fopen("board.txt", "r");
    printf("\n\t\t\tCHESS BOARD\n\n");
    printf("      a      b      c      d      e      f      g      h");
    printf("\n     |-------------------------------------------------------|\n");
    while (fgets(ch, MAXC, fd))
    {

        i = 0;
        j = 0;
        for (char *tok = strtok(ch, ","); tok; tok = strtok(NULL, ","))
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                printf("%d |", counter1);
                i++;
                counter1--;
            }

            if (j >= 8)
            {
                i == 0;
            }
            size_t len;
            tok[strcspn(tok, "\n")] = 0; /* trim '\n' from end tok */
            printf("  %s  |", tok);
            j++;
            if (j == 8)
            {
                printf(" %d", counter2);
                counter2--;
                j == 0;
            }
        }
        printf("\n  |-------------------------------------------------------|\n");
    }
    printf("      a      b      c      d      e      f      g      h");
    fclose(fd);

    printf("\n\n\nwhats your move (mv, cp, prQ, prR, prB, prK, show, exit): ");
    scanf("%s", &input);
    for (int i = 0; input[i]; i++)
    {
        input[i] = tolower(input[i]);
    }

    if (strcmp(input, show) == 0)
    {
        fp = fopen("board.txt", "r");
        if (fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("Could not open file");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("\ncontents of board.csv\n\n");
        while (fgets(input, 10, fp) != NULL)
            printf("%s", input);
        fclose(fp);
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    else if (strcmp(input, move) == 0)
    {
        printf("What Piece are you wanting to move\nEnter row(1-8): ");
        scanf("%s", &input);
        a0Row = getColRow(input);
        printf("Enter column(a-h): ");
        scanf("%s", &input);
        b0Col = getColRow(input);

        printf("\nWhere do you want to move it to\nEnter row(1-8): ");
        scanf("%s", &input);
        a1Row = getColRow(input);
        printf("Enter column(a-h): ");
        scanf("%s", &input);
        b1Col = getColRow(input);

        endPos = table[a1Row][b1Col];
        table[a1Row][b1Col] = table[a0Row][b0Col];
        table[a0Row][b0Col] = endPos;

        printf("\n\n\n");
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            //printf("\n");
            for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                printf("%s ", table[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }



//
//this is where the problem starts
//
//

        fdi = open("board.txt", O_RDWR);
        char msg[1] = "\n";
        char msg1[1] = ",";

        for(i =0; i<8;i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<8;j++)
            {
                printf("size %d ", sizeof(table[i][j]));
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        buffer = malloc(*table[0][0]);
        if (fdi != -1)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {   
                    buffer = table[i][j];
                    //removeChar(buffer, (int)NULL);
                    //strcpy(buffer,table[i][j]);
                    write(fdi, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                    write(fdi, msg1, sizeof(msg1));
                }
                write(fdi, msg, sizeof(msg));
            }
            close(fdi);
        }
    }
//
// Issue Ends here
//
//

} while (strcmp(input, exit) != 0);

printf("\n\n\n");//testing printing
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    //printf("\n");
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        //printf("table[%d][%d] = %s|", i, j, table[i][j]);
        printf("%s ", table[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

fclose(fp);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want them in the output, then don't write them. `sizeof` is not `strlen`. `buffer` is `NULL` in the code you showed.

Comment: `buffer` is a pointer, so `sizeof(buffer)` is the size of a pointer, which has nothing to do with how many characters are in the memory that `buffer` points to.

Comment: You also need to include `unistd.h` to use `write`. Your tabel also does not get filled with any meaningfull data.

Comment: `table` is a 2d array of pointers to char, and all elements of this array are NULL. So I don't understand how this program can produce the output you say it does. And where do those values -4, -2, -3 etc. come from? Please post your _actual_ code.

Comment: Some caveats re. the `sizeof` vs. `strlen` comments above : in the case of `msg` and `msg1`, using `sizeof` is entirely correct, and using `strlen` would yield the wrong result. The comments above only apply to `buffer`, where `sizeof` is wrong, and `strlen` would work iff the strings in `table` are null terminated.

Comment: @KamilCuk I added the whole program its a little messy very new at this. Tried doing sizeof(table[i][j]) since I had malloc table[][] and had memcpy before didn't work though.

Comment: @user3386109 Tried doing sizeof(table[i][j]) instead of buffer since I had malloc table[][] and had memcpy before, didn't work though but then again not sure what i'm doing right now.

Comment: @Jabberwocky sorry i didn't want to add all my messy ass code, I added it now. the values come from a text file I read from beginning of code.  link to [file content](https://pastebin.com/hJnFMbdY)

Comment: @drilldog Well, that's a whole different story now. BTW the `getColRow` can be rewritten in less than ~12 lines.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I'm sure you are right, like I said I'm very new at c and was embarrassed to post my messy ass code tbh. With all this covid19 stuff I can't really go to school and speak to my professor. For now it works up until the write() stuff :/

Comment: @Ackdari I was following this video on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W_defvKTiVc) that my Professor provided, it's working without including. I added anyway but get squiggly line at `#include<unistd.h>` saying i need to update my path but it still compiles and runs as if I didn't add it.

Comment: You need to `write(fdi, table[i][j], strlen(table[i][j]));` if it is the same table from the [Earlier Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61284169/issues-filling-2d-array-from-txt-filecsv/61285405#61285405). Or better, why `write()` and not `fputs()` or `fprintf()` or some other *formatted-output* function rather than a binary output function? From the earlier question, you could use `fprintf (fdi, j > 0 ? ",%s" : "%s", table[i][j]);` to write the output to a file instead of `stdout` as you show above.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin damn that did it, thank you! just need to fix the formatting but thats not really important. I've been going at this for so long, I was so fixated on sizeof ugh. So, I'm using write 'cause its part of the requirements of the assignment. I can only use "low-level write system calls" , here it is the [assignment](https://easyupload.io/xzel1d) if you or anyone else feeling generous and can offer more tips. I just need to work on the logic now. Thank you again! make a response so I can mark it answered :)

Comment: I downloaded it and will have time to look at it in the morning. At this hour, there is no telling how creative I may get....